# Return coordinates of a tank

Tags: coordinate, robocode

I have written some code to move a tank to specific point.  First I've made a wall stick and programmed it to find out when the tank moves to the bottom-left.  The tank's coordinate is (18,18), but when I use getWidth() and getHeight() function it returns the tank's width and height - which is (40, 40).

I think when the tank moves to the bottom-left, the coordinate should be (getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2). What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: the function getX() and getY() can returns the coordinate of tank, but what i am asking here is where is the missing 2(40/2-18) pixels?

Comment: do you still need help?